# Python: FFT of accelerometer data without knowing the sampling rate

Tags: python, fft, sensors

I created an Android app to record accelerometer data. I have set 20 Hz as the sample rate, but in Android this is a theoretical limit because depending on the situation the device can sample with a higher frequency or, in some cases, lower. Therefore, a final recording will not have a constant sampling rate over time.

This is a window of 10s of my signal:
[image]

How can I calculate the FFT without knowing the sample rate a priori?

Comment: You should resample the data to a regular sample interval, eg with [`scipy.signal.resample()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html). If you run into trouble, share an example of what the data look like and I'm sure someone can help. There are other options, like [NDFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform) or periodograms, but I'm outside my comfort zone there...

Answer (score 0):

you need to at least know the total time of sampling, so you can approximate it by interval=total_time/number_of_samples.